# FAX. Is it difficult to hook up Twilio programmable faxing to CiviCRM?

Tags: civimail, civimember

I would like to be able to use Twilio programmable faxing directly from within CiviCRM. Many of my contacts only have fax numbers (no email addresses).

I tried to put FAX in the tag section below, but, apparently my account isn't mature enough to use the "F" word.

Has anyone successfully hooked up Twilio programmable fax to CiviCRM. The Internet is silent on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing Twilio is one of the cheapest and you're already set up with them, but if you'd consider RingCentral at about 1.7c/page which is reasonable then you can still keep Twilio for other things and just use RingCentral's email-to-fax plan.

So you'd add an email address on your contact records something like `1234567890@rcfax.com`, and then use it the same way you'd use any other email address, attaching the pdf or whatever.

https://www.ringcentral.com/plansandpricing/ringcentralfax.html

https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/6643?language=en_US

There are others besides ringcentral, but that's one I'm familiar with.

UPDATE: One workaround for tracking successful transmissions using the above is to use a dedicated sending address like 'fax-notifications@myorg.org', and then set up the email processor for inbound email processing on this address (see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#autofiling-email-activities-via-emailprocessor). Then when ringcentral (or whatever) sends the transmission receipt it will get automatically filed into CiviCRM. It won't get filed on the specific contact without some extra programming, but it would at least get filed in CiviCRM.

Comment: RingCentral seems to work the same way as Faxaway. I'd like a fax solution that can keep my CiviCRM backend (database) apprised of successful and failed faxes. I'm just starting, and I'm no programmer. A Twilio FAX plugin for CiviCRM would be wonderful!

We haven't been able to find any FAX solution for any CRM system.I'd like to know if anyone has.

Comment: I understand it's not exactly what you're looking for. For what it's worth I've updated the answer with a partial idea for tracking successful faxes. It wouldn't be as complete a solution as the twilio api.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will explore it.